# How can I add a "custom" row to the top of a select result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can select and pull out a list of records by using a select statement like so with t-sql:

```
select * from [dbo].[testTable];
```

But how can I add in a "custom" row to the top of the result set?

For example, if the result set was:

```
John    john@email.com
Max     max@domain.com
```

I want to add a row, which is not from the table, to the result set so that it looks like so:

```
Name    Email
John    john@email.com
Max     max@domain.com
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I'm going to export this into a csv file through sqlcmd and I want to add in those "custom row" as headers.

Comment: FIY : sqlcmd already has options to include the header automatically into output file

Comment: @hoangnnm Can I? I tried to search for an example but I can't find a command that I can use to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the safe way to do this:

```
select name, email
from ((select 'name' as name, 'email' as email, 1 as which
      ) union all
      (select name, email, 2 as which from [dbo].[testTable]
      )
     ) t
order by which;
```

In practice, `union all` will work:

```
      select 'name' as name, 'email' as email
      union all
      select name, email from [dbo].[testTable]
```

However, I cannot find documentation that guarantees that the first subquery is completed before the second.  The underlying operator in SQL Server *does* have this behavior (or at least it did in SQL Server 2008 when I last investigated it).

Comment: I know it's an old question, but worth pointing out if you want to name headers of a CSV like the OP and one of your columns is `int` type and you want to have a set 'name', you'll need to cast the column values to `varchar` first

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name, email FROM (
   SELECT 'Name' AS Name, 'Email' AS Email, 1 AS o
   UNION ALL
   SELECT name, email, 2 AS o FROM testTable
) t
ORDER BY o, name
```

The o column is added to order the result sets of the UNION so that you ensure the first result set appears on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 'Name' as name, 'Email' as email, 1 'rank'
union 
SELECT name, email,3 'rank')a
ORDER BY a.rank,a.name
```

Try the above.

Comment: There is no order here... it could be in any order.  Also, those are the the column names he wanted for the header.