# Insert Row at top of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
select 
    Store_Desc + ' ('+Store_ID + ')' as storename  
from  
    table_name  
order by
    ID
```

Results:

```
 Apple (0051)
 Cherries (0060)
 Banana (0081)
```

On the top of the result I need another row looks like:

Result:

```
Fruits
----------------
Apple (0051)
Cherries (0060)
Banana (0081)
```

How should I need to insert top row with out changing order down (I can use temporary table if  needed)

Comment: By definition a table is an unordered set. As such the concept of inserting to the top is impossible. Order is only when pulling data from a table. And the way you establish order is with an order by clause.

Comment: @SeanLange OP has an order by clause

Comment: @paparazzo yeah. They are asking how to insert a row. Maybe they only want this as output like your answer does. Not really sure.

Comment: Do you need the row in the output, or do you want to insert the row in the table?

Comment: Probably a duplicated of 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456653/sql-server-equivalent-to-oracles-nulls-first

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Really a dup on how to sort on null ??

Comment: @paparazzo Yes fruits doesnt have StoreId. anyway that sort technique also worth better than union two queries.

Comment: "Chocolate" is a fruit?!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: Maybe this is a better duplicate, now that the question is clearer:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771349/how-can-i-add-a-custom-row-to-the-top-of-a-select-result-set  @marc_s oh yes, chocolate is my favorite fruit...not too sure about boston though.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Fruit is not in the table to sort on.

Comment: @paparazzo This shouldnt be part of the database, that is obviously part of the UI.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If it is obviously part of the UI then how is it a duplicate on sort on null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use a temporary table would need to repeat ID

```
select Store_Desc + ' (' + Store_ID +')' as storename, ID  
from table_name  
union all 
select 'fruit', '0'
order BY  ID
```

or

```
declare @T table (storename varchar(20), ID varchar(10));
insert into @T values ('fruit', '0');
insert into @T 
select select Store_Desc + ' (' + Store_ID + ')', ID  
from  table_name;
select storename 
from @T 
order by ID;
```

Comment: If the OP only wants the row in the output this is an excellent solution to that.