# Get header as the first row in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table:

```
id    name    city
--------------------
1     Jim     NewYork
2     Rose    London
3     Kitty   Seattle
......
```

The output:

```
id    name    city
--------------------
id    name    city
1     Jim     NewYork
2     Rose    London
3     Kitty   Seattle
```

I can easily do it in static SQL like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771349/how-can-i-add-a-custom-row-to-the-top-of-a-select-result-set), but how to do it in dynamic SQL?

```
Declare @sql as varchar(max)='select *';
set @sql =@sql+' from mytable';

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: How about column types? Column names are nvarchar. Do you want convert all columns values to nvarchar also? Why do you want do such thing?

Comment: @under618520 Your table and output are the same. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Seems like an [XY Problem](http://XYproblem.info).

Comment: the datatype of id is int, others are varchar. Is it possible to change the datatype of id, and add 'id' filed?

Comment: You can, but things like ordering won't be the same. `'2'` is **greater than** `'10'`, for example. You should leave numerical data types as numerical data types.

Comment: That's really a problem to be worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do that as your id looks int to me. If you want one extra string type value to the column to appear on the top, in that case you have to convert all the int to string.

Still if you want to do that you can write your query like following.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT cast(id AS VARCHAR(10)) AS id
        ,Name
        ,city
    FROM mytable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 'id'
        ,'name'
        ,'city'
    ) t
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN t.id = 'id'
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END
```

Same query can be written as dynamic query like following.

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(max) = 'select * from (
                select cast(id as varchar(10)) as id,Name,city';
SET @sql = @sql + ' from mytable union select ''id'',''name'', ''city'')t 
                      order by case when t.id=''id'' then 0 else 1 end';

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: ok, I understand your meaning, the point is changing the datatype.

Comment: yes, you can't mix datatype for a single column, it can be either int or string, but can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am overdoing this. But if you want a pure dynamic way, you can try something like

```
declare @sql varchar(max),
    @colnameHeads varchar(max), 
    @colnames varchar(max);

-- building the row with column headers
set @colnameHeads   = STUFF((
SELECT ',''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'<your-table>'
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

-- casting all the values to varchar to match with header row
set @colnames   = STUFF((
SELECT ',' +  CONCAT('CAST(', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS VARCHAR(100))')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'<your-table>'
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

-- dynamic script
set  @sql  = 'select '+ @colnameHeads  + ' union all select '+ @colnames + ' from <your-table>';

EXEC (@sql)
```