C# / Entity Framework Core: IQueryable get theoretical rank of score in queryable list of scores without instantiating list
tl;dr, I have a sorted IQueryable of user scores, and I want to get the rank of an attempt (that may or may not be in the IQueryable).
I have a class Attempt that represents an attempt of my videogame.
class Attempt(int Id, string UserId, int score)
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = Id;
    public string UserId { get; set; } = UserId!;
    public int score { get; set; } = score;
}

Let's say I have an IQueryable<Attempt> to simulate the Entity Framework Core IQueryable on the DbContext classes. I am using PostgreSQL.
var list = new List<Attempt>();

list.Add(new Attempt(1, "Joe", 20));
list.Add(new Attempt(2, "Alan", 25));
list.Add(new Attempt(4, "Joe", 30));
list.Add(new Attempt(7, "Violet", 500));
list.Add(new Attempt(5, "Violet", 10));
list.Add(new Attempt(9, "Paul", 10));
list.Add(new Attempt(66, "Paul", 10));

var queryable = list.AsQueryable();

I want to get the theoretical rank of an arbitrary attempt whether it's in the list or not, where "Rank" means the position in the list sorted by the score.
In case that there are ties, their ranks should all be the highest position they are tied for.
And I want to do this without converting the IQueryable to an IEnumerable so that we will not have to fetch the entire list of attempts from the DB ever.
Here are a few use examples:
// attempts to check
var attempt1 = new Attempt(4, "Joe", 30); // existent attempt - should return the existing attempts rank
var attempt3 = new Attempt(58, "Joel", 47); // non-existent attempt - should get the rank right after the attempt with the lowest score higher than itself
var attempt2 = new Attempt(57, "Jonathan", 30); // non-existent attempt with colliding score - should return the same rank as any existing attempt with the same score

How can I do this?

What database are you using?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Managed to solve this. Big thanks to Guru Stron for the initial idea.
So, you can solve this on List based IQueryables with the method TakeWhile or other Window Functions, however window functions are not supported in EF Core (see issue), and Guru Stron suggested to use linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore's window functions.
I ended up writing these two methods:
The first is identical to Guru Stron's answer, it creates a queryable of attempts and their ranks by utilizing Linq2db's Window functions.
IQueryable<AttemptAndRank> GetRankedQueryable(IQueryable<Attempt> attempts)
{
    return attempts.ToLinqToDB()
        .Select(a =>
            new AttemptAndRank(a, Sql.Ext.Rank().Over().OrderByDesc(a.score).ToValue()));
}

The second method, the getRank method, should get the rank of an attempt even if it isn't in the queryable, this without loading the entire list into the server.
It does this by using getRankedQueryable AsSubQuery, and giving it as param the attempts queryable Union'd with the given attempt.
long getRank(IQueryable<Attempt> attempts, Attempt attempt)
{
    var score = GetRankedQueryable(attempts.Union(new List<Attempt>{ attempt })).AsSubQuery()
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attempt.Id == attempt.Id);
    return score is not null ? score!.Rank : -1;
}


Based on this github issue currently EF Core does not support Window Functions out of the box. One of the possible options is to use linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore package which has support for them (and basically replaces the EF Core query translator). For example:
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(b=> b.UseNpgsql(...)
    .UseLinqToDB());

// ....
var array = ctx.Attempts
    .ToLinqToDB()
    .Select(a =>
        new
        {
            a.UserId,
            Rank = Sql.Ext.Rank().Over().OrderBy(a.Score).ToValue(),
        })
    // build the rest of the query
    .ToArray(); 

Possibly something can be done with "vanilla" EF Core via interceptors or user-defined function mapping, but have not tried to use those.
Another option to look at is System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.

Thank you for the suggestions! I wont have the ability to test these for a week or more, but I will be sure to read up on these until then

Tested the linq2db method now, it works as long as I build the entire query to an IEnumerable in the server, however that is not what I am looking for, as I do not want thousands of entities loaded to the server every query.
When trying to only get the rank of the specific attempt I want, the result was always rank 1, I assume this is because the rank query executes only after I've narrowed down the select to one instance.
My testing: https://gist.github.com/tomerfir/6227666dc3f8471214bfe42ec5e42fa3

Gonna read about Database functions in general, as that might help me in other places as well

@TomerTrashman please add expected results to the gist.

@TomerTrashman "it works as long as I build the entire query to an IEnumerable in the server" - that's interesting, probably you are missing some indexes, but without access to the environment it is hard to tell.

added expected results and actual results
Also, when I said that I build the entire query to an IEnumerable, I meant that I only actually get ranks if I fetch the entire list from the DB to the server, however what I want is to be able to know an attempt's rank without doing that, entirely within a single entityFramework query (or multiple, just that I wouldn't have to fetch thousands of entities to the server when its not needed)

@TomerTrashman gave a quick pick - based on the description my understanding was that you want the same rank for all same scores, so I changed to Rank from RowNumber (you can see this in the edit history). Use RowNumber for different numbers for the same score, but I suggest to add tie breaker so the rank is consistent across queries (i.e. for example order over score + id).

Hello, sorry for the delay, exam season.
I took your note about adding a tiebreaker, and additionally I managed to get the individual getRank to work by specifiying that the GetRankedQueryable is a subquery, therefore alleviating me the need to load thousands of entities into the server.
However, I still cannot get the rank of an entity that is not already in the DB. I am trying to see if I could somehow add it to the table the query is creating before I run the rank command.
See updates in gist.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771349/how-can-i-add-a-custom-row-to-the-top-of-a-select-result-set
Maybe I can do something like this...

Alright... I succeeded in making the getRank() calls not in the database work (by doing attempts.Union(new List<Attempt>{ attempt })), however 1. the values are not quite correct, specifically attempt3 (new attempt with colliding score) gets a rank one lower than the rank it should actually have, and also for some reason the program now crashes when I attempt to remove the list from the db at the end?
Updated gist again.

Ok, the wrong rankings were due to adding the thenBy to tiebreak between attempts with the same score. Now it actually works as intended, going to post the solution I came up with as an answer. also updated gist.

However it still crashes in the end with the message System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The instance of entity type 'Attempt' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
